# How to place a number in every position my horse pawn has been to (in a 2D "board" array)

Tags: java, arrays

The program basically prompts the user to pick one of the displayed moves and move the horse pawn in the chess board. Ιn this way we try to see how many times the horse can move to the chessboard without being out of bounds or even in the same position.

The problem is that I haven't figured out a way to place a number (starting from 1) for the positions where the horse has been to. More specifically I want it to print H in the current position of the horse and 1 to ... on the past positions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex7_22 {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String[][] board = new String[8][8];
    private static int[] horizontal = new int[8];
    private static int[] vertical = new int[8];
    private static boolean[][] boardPositions = new boolean[8][8];
    private static int currentRow = 3;
    private static int currentColumn = 4;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        fillArrays();
        boolean outOfBoundsV;
        boolean outOfBoundsH;
        boolean positionAvailability = false;
        int VerticalMove,HorizontalMove;
        fillBoard();
        board[3][4] = "H";
        boardPositions[3][4] = true;
        displayBoard();
        int pickMove;
        for(int i=1;i<=64;i++){
            displayBoardPositions();
            displayPossibleMoves();
            do {
                System.out.println("\nPick one of the displayed moves to do (0-7): ");
                pickMove = scanner.nextInt();
                VerticalMove = moveHorse_Vertical(pickMove);
                HorizontalMove = moveHorse_Horizontal(pickMove);
                outOfBoundsV = checkForOutOfBounds(VerticalMove);
                outOfBoundsH = checkForOutOfBounds(HorizontalMove);
                if ((outOfBoundsV)||(outOfBoundsH)){
                    reverse(pickMove);
                }
                if((!outOfBoundsV)&&(!outOfBoundsH)){
                    positionAvailability = checkForPositionAvailability(VerticalMove,HorizontalMove);
                    if((!positionAvailability)){
                        reverse(pickMove); 
                    }
                }
            }while (((outOfBoundsV)||(outOfBoundsH))||(!positionAvailability));
            board[VerticalMove][HorizontalMove] = "H";
           //placeNumber(VerticalMove,HorizontalMove,pickMove);
            boardPositions[VerticalMove][HorizontalMove] = true;
            displayBoard();
        }
    }

    /* private static void placeNumber(int VerticalMove, int HorizontalMove, int pickMove) {
        //have to place number in every position the horse has been to. Haven't managed to get it working.
        reverse(pickMove);
        int i=0;
        i++;
        String iStr = String.valueOf(i);
        board[VerticalMove][HorizontalMove] = iStr;
        currentRow += vertical[pickMove];
        currentColumn += horizontal[pickMove];
    } */

    private static void reverse(int move){
        currentRow -= vertical[move];
        currentColumn -= horizontal[move];
    }

    private static void fillBoard(){
        for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<board[i].length;j++){
                board[i][j] = "0";
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkForPositionAvailability(int vertical, int 
    horizontal) {
        if(!boardPositions[vertical][horizontal]){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You've already been in this position.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkForOutOfBounds(int position) {
        if((position<0)||(position>=8)){
            System.out.print("Position out of bounds\nPlease choose another move\n");
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    private static int moveHorse_Vertical(int move) {
        currentRow += vertical[move];
        return currentRow;
    }

    private static int moveHorse_Horizontal(int move){
        currentColumn += horizontal[move];
        return currentColumn;
    }

    private static void fillArrays() {
        //fill horizontal array
        horizontal[0] = 2;
        horizontal[1] = 1;
        horizontal[2] = -1;
        horizontal[3] = -2;
        horizontal[4] = -2;
        horizontal[5] = -1;
        horizontal[6] = 1;
        horizontal[7] = 2;
        //fill vertical array
        vertical[0] = -1;
        vertical[1] = -2;
        vertical[2] = -2;
        vertical[3] = -1;
        vertical[4] = 1;
        vertical[5] = 2;
        vertical[6] = 2;
        vertical[7] = 1;
    }

    private static void displayBoard(){
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
        System.out.println("     -----------------------------   ");
        for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
            System.out.print(i + "|\t");
            for(int j=0;j<board[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+board[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void displayBoardPositions(){
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
        System.out.println("     -----------------------------   ");
        for(int i=0;i<boardPositions.length;i++){
            System.out.print(i + "|\t");
            for(int j=0;j<boardPositions[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+boardPositions[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void displayPossibleMoves(){
        System.out.println("\n0 -> 1 move up // 2 moves right.\n" +
                "1 -> 2 moves up // 1 move right.\n" +
                "2 -> 2 moves up // 1 move left.\n" +
                "3 -> 1 move up // 2 moves left.\n" +
                "4 -> 1 move down // 2 moves left.\n" +
                "5 -> 1 move left // 2 moves down.\n" +
                "6 -> 1 move right // 2 moves down.\n" +
                "7 -> 1 move down // 2 moves right.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i don't think you need to change much. You just need to add two integers that keep track of your previous position. I tried to keep the modifications of your code to a minimum:

```
int previousRow = 3;
int previousColumn = 4;
```

and update them after you set the current position to "H":

Here is a modified version of your `public static main(String[] args)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    fillArrays();
    boolean outOfBoundsV;
    boolean outOfBoundsH;
    boolean positionAvailability = false;
    int VerticalMove,HorizontalMove;
    fillBoard();
    board[3][4] = "H";
    boardPositions[3][4] = true;
    // add the two integers that keep track of you previous position:
    int previousRow = 3;
    int previousColumn = 4;
    displayBoard();
    int pickMove;
    for(int i=1;i<=64;i++){
      displayBoardPositions();
      displayPossibleMoves();
      do {
        System.out.println("\nPick one of the displayed moves to do (0-7): ");
        pickMove = scanner.nextInt();
        VerticalMove = moveHorse_Vertical(pickMove);
        HorizontalMove = moveHorse_Horizontal(pickMove);
        outOfBoundsV = checkForOutOfBounds(VerticalMove);
        outOfBoundsH = checkForOutOfBounds(HorizontalMove);
        if ((outOfBoundsV)||(outOfBoundsH)){
          reverse(pickMove);
        }
        if((!outOfBoundsV)&&(!outOfBoundsH)){
          positionAvailability = checkForPositionAvailability(VerticalMove,HorizontalMove);
          if((!positionAvailability)){
            reverse(pickMove);
          }
        }
      } while ((outOfBoundsV)||(outOfBoundsH)||(!positionAvailability));
      // set the previous position to your current step of i:
      board[previousRow][previousColumn] = String.valueOf(i);
      board[VerticalMove][HorizontalMove] = "H";

      //update your previous position, with your current position
      previousColumn  = currentColumn;
      previousRow   = currentRow;
      boardPositions[VerticalMove][HorizontalMove] = true;
      displayBoard();
    }
  }
```